# Convert feet into mm in javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a code for converting feet to Mm its working well but i need that converted MM to be placed in text field it was displaying below to the feet text field.so kindly check the code and give me solution guys.

CODE:script

```
function LengthConverter(valNum) {
 document.getElementById("oheight1").innerHTML=valNum/3.2808;
}
```

JSP PAGE:CODE

```
<input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="FEET" 
oninput="Converter(this.value)" onchange="Converter(this.value)">
<span id="oheight1"></span>
```

Kindly check the code and tell me how to place the converted MM values in text field.

Comment: `Converter !== LengthConverter`

Comment: mm = millimetre, Mm = megametre, MM is not a unit of length. And your formula converts feet to metres. Which is the one you're after again?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Your function naming is wrong though. (LengthConverter, Converter)

```js
function LengthConverter(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("oheight1").innerHTML=valNum/3.2808;
}
```

```html
<input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="FEET" 
oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">

<span id="oheight1"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.it is working I want to place the mm converted values into text field Bro help me for that one .

Answer (score 0):

Use blur event instead, when user leaves the field it will convert the value

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function Converter(valNum) {
           document.getElementById('feet').value = valNum/3.2808;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="FEET"  onblur="Converter(this.value)">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does a different event (`blur`) fix the problem (that you've fixed by making an unattributed changed to the code)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Using javascript
var inp = document.getElementById('feet')
inp.addEventListener("input",function(){
document.getElementById("oheight1").innerHTML=inp.value/3.2808;
})
```

```html
<label>Feet</label>
<input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="FEET" 
><br/>
<p>Meters :<span id="oheight1"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thx.i want the converted mm values in text field like we give feet value in number field right like the same I want converted mm values inside the text box.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Using jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#feet").on("input",function(){
$("#oheight1").text($(this).val()/3.2808)
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Feet</label>
<input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="FEET" 
><br/>
<p>Meters :<span id="oheight1"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function convertFeetToMM(){
        let feet= document.getElementById('feet').value;
        let mm= feet*304.8;
        mm= mm.toPrecision(6);
        document.getElementById('result').value = mm;
    }

<table class="styleTable">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Enter Feet:<input type="number" id="feet" min="0"/></label></td>
            <td>feet</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button onClick="convertFeetToMM()">Convert Feet to MM</button>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><label>MM decimal result:<input type="number" id="result"/></label></td>
            <td>MM</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

This is similar to [MM to Feet](https://mm-in-inches.com/mm-to-feet.html)